# How to validate custom language syntax (add errors/warnings) in monaco editor

Tags: diagnostics, monaco-editor

Basically, I have integrated a custom built language to Monaco editor.
Now, I need to add diagnostic options to it so that syntax validation will happen.
Any possibility on this? 
I could only find a javascript based diagnostic options in https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-configure-javascript-defaults

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39957140/syntax-validation-of-a-custom-language-in-monaco-editor/42557387#42557387). I think it would be helpful