# Monaco custom language validation

Tags: monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

Monaco editor
Is there any example how to write validation for custom language ?

For example i need to write error for unused words (words is dynamic)

Comment: See my answer to this question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66070565/3160967

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is rather vague but [here is an example](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/fc9663af5c92dfb9abcaa93384d2b35893d9f4c6/lsp-sample/server/src/server.ts#L66-L88) that shows how to validate if `typescript` is all written in lowercase instead of `TypeScript`.

Comment: This is for VSCode. For Monaco which is browser based, the problem is there is no standard language server/client api?

Comment: If you're trying to use a language server, you can try looking into TypeFox's monaco-languageclient project.
https://github.com/TypeFox/monaco-languageclient